Why doesn't my UILabel update its text properly?/Why does my UILabel show the wrong text?
I have two labels, which I will refer to as labelA and labelB. I also have some buttons that trigger some code. Here is one.
@IBAction func buttonA1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if game1 == true && points > 99{
            points -= 100
            perClick1 += 1
            labelA.text = "Points Per Click: \(String(perClick1))"}}


There are multiple buttons with similar if statements and code, only changing the Integer type variables but those don't work either.
I also have another set of buttons that have the same differences between each other. Here is one.
@IBAction func buttonB1(_ sender: UIButton)           {
        if game1 == true && points > 999{
            points -= 1000
            perSec1 += 1
            labelB.text = "Points Per Second:\(String(perSec1))"}}

Here is the variable creation code:
var perSec = 0
var perClick = 1
var points = 100000


Before I press buttonA1, when I start game1, labelA reads 0 even though at the time I started game1, I set labelA to perClick1, which at creation is equal to one. After creation I did not make it decrease. However perSec is equal to 0 at creation.
When I press buttonA1, the label still shows 0. But when I press buttonB1, both labels are set to perSec1, even though only labelB is meant to. Basically, labelA is not updating when told to, instead updating when labelB is meant to update and displaying what labelB was meant to show, while labelB updates correctly. Can someone tell me what is going on and give me a solution?
I have checked all variables and made sure that all if-statements are running and they all are. I have also tried to do things like reloadInputViews() but I can't because I'm a beginner and don't know how to do things relating to firstResponder. Also I don't know how threads work but from what I have read elsewhere on stackOverflow it (the bit where labelA doesn't update when it is supposed to, not the bit where it updates to the wrong message) is about them. Can someone help(Please)?
(Side Note: In the same project, a button triggered a few if-else statements. X triggered when a variable was true. Y triggered if a variable was true and another variable was false. both variables from Y were not in X. X's variable(xv) was never true (until you pressed a button, after which you would eventually press another, setting it to false), but it(X) would trigger instead of Y. Maybe this is a similar/ related issue.)

Without a Minimal, Reproducible Example there's really not enough specifics in your question to be able to provide a solution, but based on what you said and the code provided, it sounds like your Storyboard isn't properly connected to labelA and instead have the same label connected to both labelA and labelB

I have checked the outlets and they are all connected fine. Also, can you tell me what other information you need?

Also, previously, I deleted and replaced both labels and outlets and the code still didn't work(I forgot to say this in the main question, sorry).

It helps if you format your code with braces on separate lines:
@IBAction func buttonA1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if game1 == true && points > 99 {
        points -= 100
        perClick1 += 1
        labelA.text = "Points Per Click: \(String(perClick1))"
    }
}

The 3 lines of code inside the braces will execute ONLY if game1 is true AND points is greater than 99.
Otherwise, nothing will happen.
You either need an else block, or, more likely, you want to update the label on every click/tap:
@IBAction func buttonA1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if game1 == true && points > 99 {
        points -= 100
    }
    perClick1 += 1
    labelA.text = "Points Per Click: \(String(perClick1))"
}


Edit
Use some print statements to help debug your code...
@IBAction func buttonA1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("game1:", game1, "points", points)
    if game1 == true && points > 99 {
        print("inside if block - labelA.text:", labelA.text)
        points -= 100
        perClick1 += 1
        print("setting labelA.text to:", "Points Per Click: \(String(perClick1))")
        labelA.text = "Points Per Click: \(String(perClick1))"
    }
}

Try that, and see what you get printed to the Debug Console.

As I have mentioned in my main question, game1 is true and points is greater than 99, because afterwards, points is 100 less.

@azureSparrowhawk - use print statements to debug ... see the Edit to may answer

Here's what I got:
game1: true points 1000000
inside if block - labelA.text: Optional("0")
setting labelA.text to: Points Per Click: 2

@azureSparrowhawk - and the text (on screen) in labelA doesn't change? What do you get on the next click? And.. if you change labelA's starting text to "abc" what do you get?

1.No
2.It prints:
game1: true points 999900
inside if block - labelA.text: Optional("0")
setting labelA.text to: Points Per Click: 3
And the text doesn’t change
3.With code(I have done it with code when I start game1, setting it to perClick, which is zero and it doesn’t work) or with Main.storyboard

@azureSparrowhawk - OK ... you must have some other code running that you haven't told us about. If you execute labelA.text = "Points Per... and then immediately tap the button a second time, and the debug output is inside if block - labelA.text: Optional("0") again, then some line of code elsewhere must have set it back to "0"

I will check ...

Every Time you finish clicking buttonA1, you would press another button that runs the following function:                                                                                                func showGame(){                            labelA.text = "Points Per Click: \(String(perClick))"         labelB.text = "Points Per Second: (String(perSec))"         // Unrelated code}

@azureSparrowhawk - this is confusing... You have said that tapping buttonA1 executes the code to set the labelA text doesn't update the label on the screen. What does tapping another button have to do with anything?

It's The  "other code running that I haven't told you about", but you can forget about it, I already know that it is not the problem. But if you really want to know, I am making a clicker game and Button A1 and B1 are part of an upgrades menu that is closed by pressing the other button that you are confused about to go back to the main game (where the labels are). Also, I want to remind you that when Button B1(the button to change perSec and LabelB) is pressed LabelB Changes to perSec but labelA does too.

@azureSparrowhawk - I'm really trying to help you... but, now you're saying that the label is part of a different view controller? "when Button B1(the button to change perSec and LabelB) is pressed LabelB Changes to perSec but labelA does too" -- nothing in the code you have shown could possibly do that.

No, it is all in the same view controller but they are in different views

@azureSparrowhawk - again, nothing in the code you've shown could change labelA when @IBAction func buttonB1 runs. So, unless you've connected your @IBOutlets or @IBActions wrong (such as setting both actions to button B), then some other code is setting labelA's text. Search your project for labelA.text = ( https://i.sstatic.net/GPpcPiuQ.png ) ... set breakpoints at every found line, and trace your code.
